# Conditionally add a listener based on screen size?

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

On my mobile nav I have:

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="active = !active">
 Link
</a>
```

This sets a flag and stops the anchor from firing. But when the website is at a larger screen size I wish to remove this clicking and rely on hover instead.

How can I conditionally add the `@click.prevent` listener depending on the screensize?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to prevent click or to prevent all pointer events?

Comment: I want to have `@click.prevent="active = !active">` work on mobile, but have no click handler on desktop.

Comment: I think it would be better to create handler for click event (without modifier) and prevent event within this function depends on `window.innerWidth`